# How can I install Groovy-Grails support in Eclipse or Spring STS

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy

I wanted to install the Groovy Grails Tools Suite in Eclipse, but can't see it in the market place (using Neon).

I tried to go the the GGTS home page and use the install icon which you drag into your workspace, but that did not work.

I also tried to download the full Eclipse based version of GGTS (for Mac), but it crashes immediately when opened.

Comment: Don't think ggts works any more. Try intellij community

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case unfortunately. All I really needed was the Groovy-Eclipse plugin, which I was having trouble loading also. See my answer, I was able to load it by using Spring STS.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having trouble loading the Groovy-Eclipse plugin in Neon. This is really all I needed.

I was able to load the Groovy-Eclipse plugin by using Spring STS (v 3.8.4). I had to load it via the "IDE Extensions" link on the Dashboard. Seems to be working for me, at least I was able to do what I wanted.